# PowerShell - suppress Copy-Item 'Folder already exists' error

Tags: powershell, copy-item

When I run a recursive [Copy-Item](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849793.aspx) from a folder that has sub folders to a new folder that contains the same sub folders as the original, it throws an error when the subfolders already exist.

How can I suppress this because it is a false negative and can make true failures harder to see?

Example:

```
Copy-Item "C:\realFolder\*" "C:\realFolder_new" -recurse

Copy-Item : Item with specified name C:\realFolder_new\subFolder already exists.
```

Comment: Does adding -Force solve the problem?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You could try capturing any errors that happen, and then decide whether you care about it or not:

```
Copy-Item "C:\realFolder\*" "C:\realFolder_new" -recurse -ErrorVariable capturedErrors -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$capturedErrors | foreach-object { if ($_ -notmatch "already exists") { write-error $_ } }
```

Comment: Thank you, this works.  Finally getting a chance to implement it and test today :)

Answer (score 28):

If you add `-Force` to your command it will overwrite the existing files and you won't see the error.

`-Recurse` will replace all items within each folder and all subfolders.

```
Copy-Item "C:\realFolder\*" "C:\realFolder_new" -Recurse -Force
```

Comment: Overwrite the existing folders? Or only overwrite *files* in the existing folders?

Comment: I had to do both - `-Recurse -Force`- this one got me working.

Answer (score 12):

You can set the error handling behavior to ignore using:

```
Copy-Item "C:\realFolder\*" "C:\realFolder_new" -recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

However this will also suppress errors you **did** want to know about!

Comment: Yeah... that only sorta helps :)  Is the already exists thing a bug in the Copy-Item cmdlet?  Seems like a waste of output- if it's already there and I was about to create it then who cares..  at least give me a -slientOnExistingDirs or -verbose switch, right?   Thanks for your help though.. I'll think about that option.